# Why is the bottom element from LazyVerticalGrid not going completely above the BottomNavigation in android jetpack compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

So, I am trying to display the Card elements using LazyVerticalGrid. The elements are getting displayed in two columns as I want but the last element is getting displayed only partially above the BottomNavigation like shown in the picture [this is how it's displaying](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ooL5O.png)
Below is the code of my Composable **DayScreen**

`@SuppressLint("UnusedMaterialScaffoldPaddingParameter")
@Composable
fun DaysScreen() {

```
lateinit var wordsList: List<WordsModel>
wordsList = ArrayList()
```

//  var savedCards by remember{ mutableStateOf(emptyList()) }
val context = LocalContext.current

```
wordsList =
    wordsList + WordsModel("Sunday", " रविवार(Raviwar)", R.drawable.sunday, R.drawable.save)
wordsList = wordsList + WordsModel("Monday", "सोमवार(Somvar)", R.drawable.monday, R.drawable.save)
wordsList =
    wordsList + WordsModel("Tuesday", "मंगलवार(Mangalwar)", R.drawable.tuesday, R.drawable.save)
wordsList = wordsList + WordsModel(
    "Wednesday",
    "बुधवार (Budhwar)",
    R.drawable.wednesday,
    R.drawable.save
)
wordsList =
    wordsList + WordsModel("Thursday", "गुरुवार(Guruwar)", R.drawable.thursday, R.drawable.save)
wordsList =
    wordsList + WordsModel("Friday", "शुक्रवार(Shukrawar)", R.drawable.friday, R.drawable.save)
wordsList =
    wordsList + WordsModel("Saturday", "शनिवार(Shaniwar)", R.drawable.saturday, R.drawable.save)


var searchText by remember {
    mutableStateOf("")
}

var filteredList by remember { mutableStateOf(wordsList) }

fun filteredList(query:String){
    searchText=query
    filteredList = wordsList.filter {
        it.englishName.contains(query,ignoreCase = true)||it.hindiName.contains(query,ignoreCase = true)
    }
}

val navController = rememberNavController()
//For using the object on ArrowBack Icon
val onBackPressedDispatcher = LocalOnBackPressedDispatcherOwner.current?.onBackPressedDispatcher
Scaffold(topBar = {
    Box(modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .background(
            brush = Brush.linearGradient(
                colors = listOf(
                    Color(0xFF7bd596),
                    Color(0xFF71d29c),
                    Color(0xFF49c5ac)
                )
            )
        ))
    TopAppBar(title = { Text(text = "Days") },
        modifier = Modifier.height(100.dp),
        navigationIcon = {
            IconButton(onClick = { navController.popBackStack() }) {

                Icon(
                    Icons.Default.ArrowBack,
                    contentDescription = "Back",
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(16.dp)
                        .clickable { onBackPressedDispatcher?.onBackPressed() }
                )

            }
        },
        actions = {
           searchView1(languageList = wordsList,filteredList=filteredList){quer->

               filteredList = wordsList.filter { it.englishName.contains(quer,ignoreCase = true) }
           }
        },
        backgroundColor = Color(0xFF71d29c),
        elevation = 0.dp

    )
}
) {
      Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
          LazyVerticalGrid(
              columns = GridCells.Fixed(2)
          ) {
              items(filteredList.size) {
                  Card(
                      shape = RoundedCornerShape(30.dp),
                      modifier = Modifier
                          .padding(top = 10.dp)
                          .width(180.dp)
                          .height(200.dp)
                          .clip(RoundedCornerShape(16.dp))
                          .navigationBarsPadding(),
                      elevation = 6.dp,
                  ) {
                      Box{
                          Column(
                              Modifier
                                  .fillMaxSize()
                                  .padding(5.dp)
                                  .background(
                                      brush = Brush.linearGradient(
                                          colors = listOf(
                                              Color(0xFF7bd596),
                                              Color(0xFF71d29c),
                                              Color(0xFF49c5ac)
                                          )
                                      )
                                  )
                                  .clip(RoundedCornerShape(20.dp)),
                              horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
                              verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
                          ) {
                              Image(
                                  painter = painterResource(id = wordsList[it].imageId),
                                  contentDescription = "Images"
                              )

                              Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(bottom = 5.dp))
                              Text(
                                  text = wordsList[it].englishName,
                                  color = Color(0xFF0e63b0),
                                  fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold
                              )
                              Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(bottom = 5.dp))
                              Text(
                                  text = wordsList[it].hindiName,
                                  color = Color(0xFF0e63b0),
                                  fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold
                              )
                          }
                          Image(painter = painterResource(id = wordsList[it].saveImageId), contentDescription = "Save data",
                              modifier = Modifier
                                  .padding(8.dp)
                                  .padding(top = 10.dp)
                                  .align(Alignment.TopEnd)
                          )
                      }

                  }
              }
          }
          Spacer(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().height(30.dp).align(Alignment.BottomCenter))
      }
  
}
```

}
`

I have added a Spacer below but the result is same and then I also put the LazyVerticalGrid inside a Box but nothing changes. I am expecting the bottom card from list to be completely above the BottomNavigation when I scroll the list.

Answer (score 1):

The **Scaffold** composable provides a **padding values** parameter inside it's content lambda, that parameter is used to determine the padding values of its content so that your content doesn't go under your top app bar or your bottom navigation bar.
so your code should be something like this:

```
Scaffold(/* ... */) { contentPadding ->
// Screen content
Box(modifier = Modifier.padding(contentPadding)) { /* ... */ }
}
```

You should use the content padding value in the **padding modifier** of your root composable container (in my exemple its the box).

For more info i would highly advise you to read [the documentation of the Scaffold composable](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/material#screen-content)